# Android 11: Cleartext communication not enabled for client

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application where user has to login via otp and to get the otp a request has to be made to an HTTP url.

It's working perfectly in all android versions except **ANDROID 11** stating that:

`CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client`

I added a network security config and have set `usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the manifest file. The network security config is working fine for android 9 and 10 but it doesn't work on android 11. I am using OKHTTP to make the request.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No , i tried this . I solved this by the below answer

Comment: Adding `ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT` was one of the answers to the question I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Ok , I solved it and keeping this question alive so that it may help someone with same problem. I solved it by changing the
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()

to

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT,ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS))
.build();

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the application tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Final look,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> // add this line
```

Comment: That is not the solution i tried it and it does not work  in android 11 to send request . Additional parameters have to be added to make network requests